# What will happen to the repulsive forces between two charged glass rods, on a day when the humidity is high?

Tags: electrostatics

We know that on a day when the humidity is less, two glass rods, each rubbed with silk, repel each other. What happens to the extent of repulsion when the humidity is more on that day?

Comment: The dielectric constant of the humid air increases as the humidity increases. This would cause a slight reduction in the attractive forces.

Comment: The glass rods have a surface later of moisture and water is a much better conductor than glass so the charge on the rod leaks away to Earth. Doing electrostatics experiments on a day when the humidity is high is difficult.